# IBM Cloud: Connecting SQuirreL to Databases for PostgreSQL gives SSL error

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ibm-cloud, squirrel-sql

I provisioned Databases for PostgreSQL on IBM Cloud. Now I try to connect SQuirreL to my database. However, my attempts result in this error:

> FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xx.xx.xx", user "myuser",
>   database "my-database", SSL off

Is this related to the JDBC driver or any SSL setting? The credentials say `sslmode=verify-full`, but not sure how to specify it in SQuirreL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to connect with the standard JDBC driver for PostgreSQL after changing the driver properties:

Simple, but not secure approach:
 - `ssl=true`
 - `sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

Secure, more effort:
 - download the SSL certificate as provided in the credentials
 - add `?sslmode=verify-full&sslrootcert=path-to-certificate` to the connection URI

Now SQuirrel connects to my database with IBM Cloud Databases for PostgreSQL. This also works with [Hyper Protect DBaaS](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/hyper-protect-dbaas/index.html#accessing-the-database).